# CSS footer at bottom of FORM, not body/page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having trouble with **multiple forms on the same page** where I'm trying to get the `footer` element to be at the bottom of the `section` element of the following HTML:

```
<h2>Header</h2>
<section>
<img alt="" class="left margin" src="placeholder.png" />
<form action="/" method="post">
<fieldset>
<footer class="center"><input type="submit" /></footer>
</fieldset>
</form>
</section>
```

The image `height` is greater than the form's inherit `height`. I've tried `position` without luck and it seems `Flexbox` *may* be the way to go though I haven't been able to figure it out on my own. Additionally I need the `footer` to have it's `background-color` visible across 100% of the available `width` of the `section.

Since **there are multiple forms on the same page** with this exact HTML setup (with the `footer` within the `form` and `fieldset` elements) I'm *not* trying to get the `footer` at the bottom of the page like the ten thousand other questions here on Stack, only within the `section` element itself.

No JavaScript, I need this to be a pure CSS solution.

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/11es8k8e/

**CSS**

```
* {border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
footer {background-color: #eee;}
form fieldset input {background-color: #ffc;}
img {heght: 100px; width: 100px;}
section {border: #ccc solid 1px; margin: 32px; overflow: auto;}
.left {float: left;}
.center {float: center; text-align: center;}
.right {float: right;}
```

Comment: can you post your css?

Comment: @chiliNUT Yeah, done.

Comment: isn't already at the bottom? sorry, but I think I'm missing something

Comment: @John Can you update this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/L3weg5m7/) to show us your problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/11es8k8e/

Comment: There is no `float: center`. And [classes should not be presentational](http://blog.terriblelabs.com/blog/2012/01/04/step-away-from-the-presentational-classes/), e.g. `left`, `center`, `right` are bad classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this piece of CSS:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

section{
    position: relative;
}

footer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/11es8k8e/4/

Comment: Done! Please remove the comments to keep it clean ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you...

```
* {border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
footer {background-color: #eee;}
form fieldset input[type="submit"] {background-color: #ffc; display:block; position:absolute; bottom:0px; width: calc(100% - 100px);}
img {height: 100px; width: 100px;}
section {border: #ccc solid 1px; margin: 32px; overflow: auto; position:relative;}
.left {float: left;}
.center {float: center; text-align: center;}
.right {float: right;}
```

You need to set positions to the elements within the section...

Comment: Unfortunately @Imgonzalves tried that too, it's a static solution and I don't do static. The image dimensions can change and so I'd have to change more than one thing (`calc`). Thank you for trying regardless.

Comment: the img had a static size... how will it change?

Comment: In the question I stated, "**there are multiple forms on the same page**" with the exact same HTML and thus images...but the images in each form could be used for different purposes.  Dynamic code is more difficult but worth the trouble in the end when you begin to realize how much you can truly get out of it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox it would be something like

```
section, form {
  display: flex;
}
form > :first-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
form, form :first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

However, [`display: flex` does not work on `fieldset`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078681/why-cant-fieldset-be-flex-containers). You can use another element, like `div`.

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
}
form input {
  background-color: #ffc;
}
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
section {
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
  margin: 32px;
  overflow: auto;
}
section, form {
  display: flex;
}
form >:first-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
form, form :first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img alt="placeholder avatar" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m07n.gif" />
  <form action="" method="get">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label for="test1">Test 1</label>
        <input id="test1" />
      </div>
      <footer>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
      </footer>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
<section>
  <img alt="placeholder avatar" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m07n.gif" />
  <form action="" method="get">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label for="test2">Test 2</label>
        <input id="test2" />
      </div>
      <footer>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
      </footer>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
<section>
  <img alt="placeholder avatar" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m07n.gif" />
  <form action="" method="get">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label for="test3">Test 3</label>
        <input id="test3" />
      </div>
      <footer>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
      </footer>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```