# Fieldset child with height 100% is too big

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to stretch a `fieldset` child to 100%, but the child (`ul`) is too big and some overflow appears (is cut in my case).

How can I stretch the `fieldset` child to 100%, but without overflow?

```css
fieldset {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: #ffffbb;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>How to stretch child</legend>
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Just in case here is also external fiddle: [Example in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zp966jog/1/).

**Edited:**

Setting height to specific pixel is necessary. I get form layout (design) through WebSocket from C# windows application. Every component is position absolute with exact same properties as in C# application. That means, left, top, width and height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

Add this to your code:

```
ul { margin: 0; }
```

```css
fieldset {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>How to stretch child</legend>
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

### Explanation

The `ul` has default top and bottom margins added by the [browser's style sheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html).

[image]

These margins, when added to `height: 100%`, cause the overflow.

But even when the overflow issue is fixed, item #8 is packed tightly to the container's bottom edge:

[image]

This is because the `line-height` of the `legend` also creates height ([demo with `line-height: 0`](https://jsfiddle.net/zp966jog/3/))

Here are two ways you can handle this:

1. Define a height for the legend and then adjust the height of the `ul`. Something like this:

   ```
   legend {
      height: 15px;
   }

   ul {
      height: calc(100% - 15px);
   }
   ```

   [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zp966jog/4/)
2. Reduce the height of the `ul`, like this:

   ```
   ul { height: 95%; }
   ```

   [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zp966jog/5/)

Comment: Hi. height: calc(100% - 1em); solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use **Auto Height** for your `fields` and add **Height, Line-height**  for your `li`.

Its work clear and nicely.

**EDIT:** And of course you need to remove the **Overflow: hidden;** property;

```css
fieldset {
    height: auto;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: #ffffbb;
}

li {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>How to stretch child</legend>
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I can not set width to auto. (I edit my original post where I explain why).

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox doesn't work in `<fieldset>` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078681/why-cant-fieldset-be-flex-containers).

You can use a `<div>` instead [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrGjWG).

## HTML

```
<div class='fieldset'>
  <legend>aHow to stretch child</legend>
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.fieldset {
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
ul {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: #ffffbb;
}

legend {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Not quite right. A `fieldset` cannot be a flex container (and it isn't in this question). A flex container inside a `fieldset` shouldn't be a problem.