# CSS order property does not work when applied to a fieldset element in Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The HTML `fieldset` tag is not working in display flex, order property. But it works with a `div` tag.

```css
.fset {
  display: flex;
}

.fset .first {
  order: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
}

.fset .second {
  order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="fset">
  <div class="first">
    <p>first</p>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <p>second</p>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It works in the live demo in your question when I test it. Are you testing using an obsolete browser that does not support Flexbox properly?

Comment: @Quentin, I am using chrome browser, but it's not working. If working means which browser.

Comment: Fieldset cannot be flex containers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078681/why-cant-fieldset-be-flex-containers . But you can get it working by adding divs inside it and applying flex property to div instead.

Comment: This looks like a Chrome-specific bug. I can reproduce the problem in Chrome 62, but not in Safari 11, or in Firefox 57

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal I can't add any div tag. Any other alter solutions.

Comment: @Quentin, Thanks. Any alter solution. Without javascript.

Comment: @Quentin It is a bug...check dupe link

Comment: @tamilselvan No, you can't apply `display: flex` on some elements (see dupe link), so you need to add an extra wrapper between the inner `div` and the `fieldset`.

Comment: @LGSon, Ok thanks. I will do.

Comment: You're welcome ... and it is a simple fix: https://jsfiddle.net/tmx0wydc/

Comment: @LGSon, I understand, am working in Magento so I can't add extra div. This is my problem.

Comment: Ok...you can use `float` to swap order: https://jsfiddle.net/tmx0wydc/1/

Comment: @LGSon, Yes. but I need result is one by one order. Is this possible on float right. I have used width: 100%. It's not working.

Comment: It depends if you can give them a width... https://jsfiddle.net/tmx0wydc/2/

Comment: @LGSon Thanks, My requirement is one by one bottom. my sample https://jsfiddle.net/tamilselvancst/n4Ly5w9b/3/