# How can I align three elements in a legend tag in the same line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment, legend

I have three elements: a letter in a `<h1>` tag, a `<hr />` tag and an image.
This is how they are in html:

```
<h1 class="red">&nbsp A &nbsp</h1>
<hr />
<img src="Immagini\images1.png">
```

I put all into a `<legend>` tag, like this:

```
<legend align="right"><h1 class="red">&nbsp A &nbsp</h1><hr /><img src="Immagini\images1.png"></legend>
```

but the elements are not aligned in the same line, they are one over the other.
How can I align all the elements in the same line?
This is the complete html:

```
<fieldset class="accordion"><legend align="right"><h1 class="red">&nbsp A &nbsp</h1><hr /><img src="Immagini\images1.png"></legend></fieldset>
```

The `class="red"` is only to give the red color.
The `class="accordion"` only contains this:

```
.accordion {
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.4s;
border-left-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
padding: 0%;
border-top-style: outset;
}
```

Definitely, I want something like this:

```html
<hr width="45%" style="float: left" /><h1 class="red" style="float: left">&nbsp A &nbsp</h1><hr width="15%" style="float: left" /><img src="Immagini\images1.png" style="float: left">
```

but all aligned on the same line and using the `<fieldset>` border instead of the `<hr />` left tag.
An example of the fieldset I use can be found here: [Animated Series](http://animatedseries.altervista.org/).

Solved with this:

```css
.rightalign {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.accordion {
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.4s;
border-left-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
padding: 0%;
border-top-style: outset;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="accordion"><legend style="width: 52%" align="right"><h1 class="rightalign" style="color: red">&nbsp A &nbsp</h1><hr width="45%" class="rightalign" color="#e3e3e3" /><img src="Immagini\images1.png" class="rightalign">
</legend></fieldset>
```

But now, when I change the size of the window, all returns not aligned.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, that's a great question with lots of good code examples :)

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: I sure can. You've marked an answer below as correct - did it not answer the question for you? If not you can click the green tick again to unmark it.

Comment: It answered my first question, but i edited it because the method worked but there is another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        /*css part */
          h1,hr,img
             {
                display:inline-block;
                vertical-align:middle;
              }
             /* this will work */
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline` (this prevents width and height) and `display:inline-block` in style attribute for same line.
However you can easily use `display:flex` on the parent of these elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block` for both legend and inner element. 
Here is the code sample-

```css
.accordion {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    padding: 0%;
    border-top-style: outset;
}
.legend {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="accordion">
  <legend class="legend">
    <hr style="display:inline-block" width="45%"/><h1 class="red" style="display:inline-block">&nbsp A &nbsp</h1><hr width="15%" style="display:inline-block"/><img style="display:inline-block" src="Immagini\images1.png">
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

You can also use `display:flex` but the problem is with the `fieldset` and `legend` tags. `fieldset` and `legend` tag not work with `flexbox`. You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078681/why-cant-fieldset-be-flex-containers) for more details.