# Chrome horizontal centering with flexbox

Tags: html, css

Is there a bug with certain versions of Chrome that fail for horizontal centering with Chrome? The code below is a fairly simple center with flexbox that works fine on Firebox 62 but **does not center** on both Chrome 69 and 70 :-(

```css
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
     <input type="text" id="password"></input>
     <p>Some dummy text</p>
     <button class="button-primary">Login</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure why you even need flexbox .. a simple `text-align:center` on the fieldset will do it. Better avoid complex code when it's easy.

Comment: It sure does. But I'm just surprised that such a base flexbox case renders so differently between Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: bug happens ;) especially when dealing with non-common elements like fieldset. If you use a div instead it will work. There is probably a particular Spec for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that has existed since `flex` was first implemented in Blink.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375693

Various other browsers and engines have had this issue in the past ([Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869), [Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=169082)) but have been fixed. Blink is the last major engine that, to date, has not correctly implemented `flex` in a `<fieldset>` element.

See also [Why can't <fieldset> be flex containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078681/why-cant-fieldset-be-flex-containers)