# Grid properties not working with Fieldset element

Tags: html, css, css-grid

If a `fieldset` element is set to `display: grid`, `grid-gap` will not work.

```css
fieldset#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id='grid'>
  <div class='child'>
    <div>gc1</div>
    <div>gc2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='child'>c2</div>
  <div class='child'>c3</div>
  <div class='child'>c4</div>
  <div class='child'>c5</div>
</fieldset>
```

```css
div#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'>
  <div class='child'>
    <div>gc1</div>
    <div>gc2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='child'>c2</div>
  <div class='child'>c3</div>
  <div class='child'>c4</div>
  <div class='child'>c5</div>
</div>
```

You can change the `fieldset` to a `div`, and everything works fine. Exact same code. The only difference is the element.

**Why is this the case?**

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: grid like flex will not work with fieldset: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28078681/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif according to MDN, its a bug with Chrome and Edge. i just tested in Firefox and seems to be working fine there.

Comment: @Michael_B can you explain how this is a duplicate of that other question??

Comment: in all the cases you shouldn't rely on it. button and fieldset are special elements and should not be considered for complex layout.

Comment: @TemaniAfif that boggles my mind. not being able to change the `display` property of only two elements (`fieldset` and `legend`) is simply absurd

Comment: @Anthony, a simple cursory glance at the duplicate will reveal to you why it's a duplicate, and provide you with a useful solution.

Comment: @Michael_B it was joke, hence the "lol". try to let loose for once :p