# details element seems to ignore display flex or grid?

Tags: html, css, specifications

This seems quite bizarre to me. You can see that we have a simple details element which *should by all rights* run horizontal. But it does not. `grid` also seems to not work.

Why? I am not seeing anything in the spec about the layout model being any different for these elements.

```css
details {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<details open>
 <summary>foo</summary>
 <div>bar</div>
 <div>baz</div>
</details>
```

Comment: avoid it on *special* element because they aren't designed to be flexbox or Grid container. Related : https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/28078681/8620333 (same issue with other elements)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot overide the display behavior of a details element, but if the idea is to get children on a single line , then you can use `display` or `float` on the children :

a few example **to test** through different browsers **before use**.

*borders, colors and background added for visual testing purpose*

```css
details {clear:both;margin:2em;border:solid;color:red;}
details.flkid {overflow:auto;/* to deaal with floatting children*/}
summary {background:yellow;}
details > *{padding:0 1em;color:green}
details.flkid > *{float:left;}
details.ib > *{display:inline-block;}
details.tbcl > *{display:table-cell;}
/* and so on with inline-table,inline-flex,inline-grid */
```

```html
<details class="flkid" open>
  <summary>foo</summary>
    <div>bar</div>
    <div>baz</div>
</details>
<details class="ib" open>
  <summary>foo</summary>
    <div>bar</div>
    <div>baz</div>
</details>
<details class="tbcl" open>
  <summary>foo</summary>
    <div>bar</div>
    <div>baz</div>
</details>
```

**Disclaimer : the following snippets stands here only for the fun and should NOT be seen as a solution even if it seems to work in a few browsers :**

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
}

details {
  display: contents/* removed from the flow, so the grid div becomes the parent */
}

div {
  border: solid;
  margin: 2px
}

details[open]> :not(summary) {
  /* hide them from the flow except for summary */
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}

div[class] {
  grid-row:  span 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <details><!-- attribute open removed you can add it if you want it closed at first :( -->
    <summary>foo</summary>
    <div>bar</div>
    <div>baz</div>
    <div>bar</div>
    <div>baz</div>
    <div>bar</div>
    <div class>bazbazbazbazbazb</div>
    <div>bar</div>
    <div>baz</div>
    <div>bar</div>
    <div>baz</div>
    <div>bar</div>
    <div>baz</div>
  </details>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting - cool workarounds. What I haven't been able to find is any official or even semi-official docs about this behavior. So that's what I'm pretty confused by

Comment: @GeorgeMauer just added a tricky snippet example with display:contents to keep the toggle effect of detail, but my advise would be to use javascript and drop details aside if you want a grid or flex display.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by adding the solution below.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex>* {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<details open>
  <summary>foo</summary>
  <div class="flex">
    <div>bar</div>
    <div>baz</div>
  </div>
</details>
```

Comment: well no...that doesn't make the contents of `details` to be flex, just the contents of this `.flex` class you created, that's no different than any other usage of flexbox. `foo` is still on its own. Either way the question is more about why this behavior happens and where it is spec'ed

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little old, but still relevant. I've just been confronted with it and ended up using a custom HTML tag and a line of javascript to overcome the problem.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(`custom-summary`)].forEach(e => e.onclick = () => e.closest(`custom-details`).toggleAttribute(`open`));
```

```css
custom-details > custom-summary {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: list-item;
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: disclosure-closed;
}
custom-details[open] > custom-summary {
    list-style-type: disclosure-open;
}
custom-details:not([open]) > *:not(custom-summary) {
    display: none;
}




custom-details, details {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Normal details</summary>
  <p>Content #1</p>
  <p>Content #2</p>
  <p>display:grid not working</p>
</details>


<custom-details>
  <custom-summary>Custom details</custom-summary>
  <p>Content #1</p>
  <p>Content #2</p>
</custom-details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite this question is quite old, I found some quite hacky workaround to place summary and dropdown content into one horizontal axis. The caveat is the width of `<summary>` element should be fixed, but in my case (`<summary>` is an iconic button that is 24px in width and height) it works perfectly. So you apply `position: absolute` to `<summary>` and adjust all the other things by paddings. My case below, maybe it helps someone.

```css
/* .panel is my <details class="panel"> */
.panel { 
  position: fixed; /* just my case, may be relative or absolute */
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 34px 10px 10px 34px; /* top and left padding are 10px + <summary>'s size */
  background: #ddd;
}

.panel summary {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute; /* this is the trick */
  left: 10px; /* imitate padding */
  top: 10px; /* imitate padding */
}

.panel summary::marker,
.panel summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
  content: none; /* remove triangle (my case, it is button-like) */
}

.panel[open] {
  /* the 2nd part of the trick
   * remove button's size from top padding when details are open,
   * hence left padding remains the same.
   * so visually it looks like placed into one horizontal row
   * with details' dropdown content. 
   */
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```