# Css style works in Safari, but displays different in chrome/safari.Does Flex work differently in Chrome/firefox? what am i missing?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, flexbox, alignment

i've been scratching my head all day, not knowing where to look.
The first image(left), Safari output is the result i'm expecting, but somehow in Chrome it works differently. My only conclusion is that flex works differently on chrome, but i'm not sure.

I know my css works, because i can get the expected output in safari.
I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Any suggestions or links is very much appreciated. thanks.

[image: Safari]
[image: Chrome]

```
fieldset.property{ 
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;

    display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap;
    border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid currentcolor;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
fieldset.reference{
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;

    display: flex; 
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid currentcolor;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.radio_wrap, .unit_wrap{border: 1px solid yellow;}
fieldset.property .radio_wrap{
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;

    flex: 0 0 30%;
    display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
fieldset.property .unit_wrap{
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;

    flex: auto;
    display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

Comment: You should post your code. It'll be easier to troubleshoot. 
Most likely you need to specify nowrap.

Comment: @AustinJones, it does have nowrap, which is the result i'm expecting(left img), which i did get in safari.

Comment: Without seeing the css there isn't any we can do but guess. Are you using vendor prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

Bro try this

```
display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
```

Worked for me

Comment: code posted: unit_wrap/radio_wrap are the 2 yellow bordered boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what was wrong with my code, long story short, one cannot set fieldset to display:flex.
Thanks to all who tried to help.

reference:
[Why can't <fieldset> be flex containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078681/why-cant-fieldset-be-flex-containers)